# Connecting to a database from another application

Tags: 7, database

What is the proper way to do a remote connection to my Drupal database from a remote application? I am trying to integrate IPB with Drupal so I would like to modify my Drupal database from IPB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you asked, the "correct" way would be to implement a simple web-service in Drupal in order to perform these tasks remotely from your application.  You could build a simple RESTful API to handle all your CRUD needs, for example.

The [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) is an excellent starting-point.

The reasoning for this is that you should really avoid modifying your Drupal database directly (unless you really know what youy are doing) and even if you must, connecting to it directly from another application is not only bad practice but a security risk too!

Please reconsider and use a webservice-approach, think of the kittens! :)

Comment: So this correct way isn't what most people go for?

Comment: Using Drupal's hooks, any module can add additional behaviors on data insert and updates. Direct access to the database means you bypass all these added behaviors.